# Multiple Firestore changes with batch vs cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In a chat app, if I add a new message to the messages collection, I also need to update that particular chat's document in another collection to show the last message and the time when it was sent. Right now I am triggering a cloud function every time a new message comes, in order to update the metadata for the chat. Am I doing the right thing or would it be more appropriate to use Batched writes instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference that you might be aware of when using one approach vs. the other. When using a batch write, according to the official documentation:

> You can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

This means that those simultaneous updates that are made in this **atomic** way, either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

In case you are using a function that is triggered once a message is sent, it means that you are performing two separate actions. The first one is to send a message and the second one is to update some metadata once the message is successfully sent. In this case, you can send a message but your function may fail, according to the official documentation:

> By default, without retries enabled, the semantics of executing a background function are "best effort." This means that while the goal is to execute the function exactly once, this is **not** guaranteed.

This are the reasons [why background functions fail to complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#semantics_of_retry):

> On rare occasions, a function might exit prematurely due to an internal error, and by default the function might or might not be automatically retried.
>
> More typically, a background function may fail to successfully complete due to errors thrown in the function code itself. Some of the reasons this might happen are as follows:
>
> - The function contains a bug and the runtime throws an exception.
> - The function cannot reach a service endpoint, or times out while trying to reach the endpoint.
> - The function intentionally throws an exception (for example, when a parameter fails validation).
> - When functions written in Node.js return a rejected promise or pass a non-null value to a callback.

The workaround in this case, is to [use retry to handle transient errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#best_practices).

Comment: So I think in my scenario using batch writes is the right way to go right? I don't want inconsistencies of the type: The message is sent but the metadata aren't updated because a function call failed.

Comment: In this case, you should go ahead with the batch writes.